# How to check in JSF if string empty in 'rendered' attribute

Tags: jsf, el

I want to render different primefaces components based on thr string value. How to check if the string is empty in 'rendered' attribute?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `empty` EL operator:

```
<p:someComponent rendered="#{not empty suchBean.veryStringWow}"/>

<p:differentComponent rendered="#{empty suchBean.veryStringWow}"/>
```

If the bean String property is empty or null, the "different component" is rendered.

Comment: working.. thank you :)